# Selenium Node on MAC

Tags: macos, selenium

Tried starting hub and node using the below commands.

java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar -role hub -port 1234

java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar -role node -hub http://x.x.x.x:1234/grid/register -browser "browserName=safari,setjavascriptEnabled=true,acceptSslCerts=true,maxInstances=5,Platform=MAC" -port 1235

While trying to start the browser(new RemoteWebDriver), getting the below error.

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session cannot find : {acceptSslCerts=true, browserName=safari, javascriptEnabled=true}

what could be the reason for the error, also when I tried to start the node with platform=MAC(small letter "p" for platform) it throws an error
ILlegalArgumentException:No enum constant org.openqa.selenium.Platform.MAC

Any separate drivers are required for safari browsers on MAC.? The firewalls are turned off on the MAC and also could notice a message on hub window INFO:Got a request to create a new session: {acceptSslCerts=true, browserName=safari, javascriptEnabled=true}, but nothing happens after that.

Safari version used : 7.0
MAC : 10.9

Thanks in advance.

-Ashwhin.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and got it working on my mac with these versions

```
09:46:08.422 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 25.20-b23
09:46:08.423 INFO - OS: Mac OS X 10.9.4 x86_64
09:46:08.432 INFO - v2.41.0, with Core v2.41.0. Built from revision 3192d8a
```

server

```
selenium-server -role hub -hubHost localhost
```

safari driver

```
selenium-server 
   -role node -hubHost localhost -hubPort 4444 
   -browser "browserName=safari,setjavascriptEnabled=true,acceptSslCerts=true,maxInstances=5,Platform=MAC"
   -port 1235
```

I installed selenium (v2.41.0) with brew and its Oracle java version "1.8.0_20"
So it could by the version of selenium or Java

Answer (score 0):

To Sync with HUB xx.xx.xx.xx or xx.com

hit these commands in CMD of MAC
irr-respect of HUB OS choice 
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.7.7.jar -role node -hub http://xx.xx.xx.xx:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=safari,platform=MAC -port 5559

java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.7.7.jar -role node -hub http://xx.xx.xx.xx:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=chrome,platform=MAC -port 5557 -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/path/to/my/chrome/driver